# The argument type 'Widget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout

```
class DetailChatPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget header() {
      return PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70),
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor1,

        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor3,
      appBar: header(),
    );
  }
}
```

i get an error in my code that is
The argument type 'Widget' cannot be set to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'
how to solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you declared your `header` method with the type `Widget`. You should instead declare it with the type `PreferredSizeWidget`.

```
PreferredSizeWidget header() {
  return PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70),
    child: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor1,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
Widget header() {
  return PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70),
    child: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor1,

    ),
  );
}
```

to

```
PreferredSize header() {
  return PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(70),
    child: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor1,

    ),
  );
}
```